# Custom Reply-to setting doesn't stick

Tags: civimail, drupal

I'm trying to use new feature Custom Reply-to introduced in CiviCRM 4.6 (4.6.8 now installed).  I go into Admin/CiviMail/Mailer Setting and click the Yes radio button, then save.  A Reply-to field now appears on the message preparation form, and the feature appears to work fine.  However, when I go back to Admin/CiviMail/Mailer Settings the Custom Reply-to radio buttons are both blank (unselected), with neither Yes or No selected.  This same issue exists in both my test and production systems.  The sandbox does not have this issue so there is probably something amiss in my database(s).  Which table is supposed to store this setting, and can I best repair the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's stored in `civicrm_settings` with a `group_name` of `Mailing Preferences` and a `name` of `replyTo`.

As a tangential note, this feature also existed in Civi 4.5.

Comment: Thanks. This table row does exist, and I see that its value changes between [s:1:"0";] and [s:1:"1";] (my brackets) depending on my selecting the No and Yes radio buttons. The created_date also changes accordingly. However, my original quandary remains --  when I return to the Mailer Settings panel neither of the radio buttons is selected. If I then hit "save" (having made no changes) the value of replyTo gets set to NULL. I have taken care to clear all Drupal caches and tested with three different browsers.